# Questions about policy of taxation

Tags: meaning-in-context

从使用年份起免征城镇土地使用税5年，第6年至第10年减半征收；超过500万元部分，减半征收企业所得税;国家重点扶持的高新企业，减按15%的税率征收企业所得税。

These are excepts from the favorable policies given by a local government in China. I do not really and fully understand the meaning, especially the words 减半, which literally means cutting half, but what is the total? 减按15% means what? The rate or the total?

Answer (score 1):

u have to read that all,combine them and think what it means."减半",when u compare to above,u will know it is half of the originl。(比原来减少一半).e.g:the first year to fifth year u have to pay tax to goverment like 5 yuan,th sixth to 10th u only need to pay 2.5 yuan(减半).

15％,when u see above,u know that when  ur company is not in the goernment's support project,ur have to pay like 25% tax,but if ur company is in the special project,u just happily need to pay 15% tax.｡◕‿◕

Comment: In the original text, there is no need to pay the tax in the first five years.

Comment: it just a e.g。not a translation.